remixable and enableAutoChapters in YouTube API
I'm currently using the YouTube Data API v3 to automate video uploads for my project. While most of the metadata fields are working fine, I've encountered issues with the following:
remixable: I would like to control whether the video is remixable or not, but I couldn’t find any documentation on this field. Is it supported by the API, or is there another way to set this property programmatically?
enableAutoChapters: I attempted to use this field to enable or disable automatic chapters for a video (enableAutoChapters: true/false), but it doesn’t seem to have any effect. Is this property exposed in the API, or is there an alternative way to handle it?
Here’s an example of how I’m passing these fields in the metadata:
body = {
    "snippet": {
        "title": "Test Video",
        "description": "Test Description",
        "tags": ["test", "api"],
        "categoryId": "22"
    },
    "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "public",
        "remixable": True,
        "enableAutoChapters": False
    }
}

Despite being included in my request, these fields seem to have no effect. I’ve gone through the API documentation and forums but couldn’t find a definitive answer.
Has anyone successfully used these fields, or is there a different approach to achieve this functionality? Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!
